# how to call method of abstract class in javascript

Tags: javascript, reflection, ecmascript-6

I have an abstract class that implements some methods on its prototype and I want to create an instance directly of this class without subclassing it.

I can instantiate that class by creating a `Proxy` and trapping `construct` and it seems to work. Properties of the new instance are set correctly but I have a hard time calling its methods.

```js
function AbstractNumbers(...args) {
  if (new.target === AbstractNumbers) {
    throw new Error('Cannot instantiate abstract class');
  }
  this.numbers = args;
}
AbstractNumbers.prototype.showNumbers = function() { console.log(this.numbers); }

const AbstractNumbersProxy = new Proxy(AbstractNumbers, {
  construct(target, args) {
    // change 3rd argument to bypass new.target test
    return Reflect.construct(target, args, function() {});
  }
});

const n = new AbstractNumbersProxy(1, 2, 3);

// set prototype back to AbstractNumbers
Object.setPrototypeOf(n, AbstractNumbers);

// n.__proto__ shows the correct prototype
console.log(n.__proto__);

// property n.numbers is set correctly
console.log(n.numbers);

// calling its prototype method fail
n.showNumbers();
```

How can I properly instantiate that abstract class so that I am able to call its methods?

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean? `construct` is a trap for constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
// set prototype back to AbstractNumbers
Object.setPrototypeOf(n, AbstractNumbers);
```

you've set the prototype back to the constructor function instead of its `prototype` property. Try

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(n, AbstractNumbers.prototype);
```

instead:

```js
function AbstractNumbers(...args) {
  if (new.target === AbstractNumbers) {
    throw new Error('Cannot instantiate abstract class');
  }
  this.numbers = args;
}
AbstractNumbers.prototype.showNumbers = function() { console.log(this.numbers); }

const AbstractNumbersProxy = new Proxy(AbstractNumbers, {
  construct(target, args) {
    // change 3rd argument to bypass new.target test
    return Reflect.construct(target, args, function() {});
  }
});

const n = new AbstractNumbersProxy(1, 2, 3);

// set prototype back to AbstractNumbers
Object.setPrototypeOf(n, AbstractNumbers.prototype);

// n.__proto__ shows the correct prototype
console.log(n.__proto__);

// property n.numbers is set correctly
console.log(n.numbers);

// calling its prototype method fail
n.showNumbers();
```

Please do not ask me to investigate what you are doing.